# Why does XCTAssertEqual not take NSRange as arguments even after I added "==" for NSRange?

Tags: swift

Sample code:

```
import XCTest

func == (lhs: NSRange, rhs: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return lhs.location == rhs.location && lhs.length == rhs.length
}

class NSRangeInXCTAssertionEqualTests: XCTestCase {
    func testNSRange() {
        XCTAssertEqual(NSMakeRange(1, 3), NSMakeRange(2, 5))
    }
}
```

The warning said: Cannot invoke 'XCTAssertEqual' with an argument list of type '(NSRange, NSRange)'.

Is it because NSRange is actually a Tuple? If I recall correctly, I came across the same thing when I want to place Tuples, too.

Thanks in advance,

Liwei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because you forgot to declare NSRange as Equatable:

```
extension NSRange : Equatable {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some more information since I did not calm down and read the guide at the first place. Following is what [Apple's programming guide says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267):

> If a type already conforms to all of the requirements of a protocol,
>   but has not yet stated that it adopts that protocol, you can make it
>   adopt the protocol with an empty extension
>
> Types do not automatically adopt a protocol just by satisfying its
>   requirements. They must always explicitly declare their adoption of
>   the protocol.